# Grid item outside container

Tags: html, css

I making app with comments and the problem is that when comment is long it goes out from the container and it does not look good. Is there way to wrap comment when it is to long and auto-push to next row and keep it in the "box"? I just want to overflowing part of comment push to the next row.

html:

```
<div class="comment-section-grid">
    <div class="comment-section">
        {% for comment in comments %}
            <div class="comment">
                <div><img class="comment-user-picture" src="{{user.profile.user_image.url}}"></div>
                <p class="comment-user">{{user.username}}</p>
                <p class="user-comment-content">{{comment.content}}</p>
            </div>                   
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.comment-section-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}



.comment {
    margin: 2rem 0rem 2rem 0rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 6rem) ;
    grid-template-rows: 4.5rem;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(168, 167, 167);;
}

.user-comment-content{
   grid-row: 2/3;
   grid-column: 2/3;
   margin-top: -1rem;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a max-width to the `.comment` ? or setting width: 100% ?

Comment: It does not work sir

Answer (score 0):

Try to use.

```
word-wrap:break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

into the`user-comment-content`.

```
.comment-section-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}



.comment {
    margin: 2rem 0rem 2rem 0rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 6rem) ;
    grid-template-rows: 4.5rem;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(168, 167, 167);;
}

.user-comment-content{
   grid-row: 2/3;
   grid-column: 2/3;
   margin-top: -1rem;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is using the CSS property "word-break", doc found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

The property sets whether line breaks appear wherever the text will overflow its container.

I suggest maybe specifically trying "word-break: normal".

One other suggestion is using the CSS "white-space" property. Doc found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space This sets how white space inside an element is handled. For your solution you may need to use "white-space: normal".

Best of luck